# Can I perform a partial compilation to get class metadata?

Tags: c#, compilation, attributes, xml-documentation

I have a project where I am mining metadata, specifically attributes and custom xml documentation comments, from a particular dll that is created in another C# project.  The mining is aimed at finding all methods with particular attributes and/or documentation comments in the dll.  I use Assembly.LoadFrom and GetTypes (and additional processing) to find all of the attributes, and I parse the generated XML documentation file to access the custom documentation comments.  I have the functionality working fine, but there is a lot of extra overhead needed to get things to work.

The project being mined does not need to execute, but needs to be compiled in order to have a dll from which I can extract the attributes and to generate the XML document.    Unfortunately, this target project depends, directly or indirectly, on 10 other projects.  These additional projects provide exactly zero benefit other than allowing the target project to compile.  But I have to pull these additional 10 projects into my solution just because.

Is it possible to perform some sort of partial compilation of the project in question without having the projects upon which it depends in the solution?  Can I get the type information (from which I mine attributes) and the XML documentation some other way?

Comment: You might want to check out [Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/dotnet-compiler-platform-roslyn-extensibility?view=vs-2022). But the actual goal is somewhat unclear. Is intended for real time feedback to the developer, like an visual studio extension? Or to provide offline metadata, perhaps better suited as a build-step? Or perhaps to provide runtime data about the loaded dll?

Comment: I am trying to track requirements and automated tests.  We are using NUnit for our automated testing, and tests are identified by an NUnit attribute [Test].  We also list the requirements that each test verifies with custom xml documentation comments.  So, it's offline, but not really a build step.  It's for tracking requirements before a full test effort is initiated.

Comment: Oh, Roslyn looks interesting at first blush.  I will look into it deeper.

Comment: We did something similar by using a separate test tool that is called with the test-dll as an argument. This would then do any preparation work, call Nunit for the actual test-execution, write reports to TeamCity etc. You might be able to package such a tool as nuget package for intergration with build systems etc. To me it sounds like sounds like a typical build-step to be run by the CI system. I.e. if requirement is set to 'complete' without a matching test -> build fail.